# not able to read all rows from geodataframe of GDB

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

I'm trying to read the geodatabase file using geopandas.
I'm able to read it but it only taking 10 rows in GeoDataFrame.
In my file there rows around 25000.
I want whole data in memory to do some operation
I'm using following function to read data.

```
gdf = gpd.read_file("%s" % gdb_file_path, layer=layer)
```

Also tried iving rows but didn't work.

```
gdf = gpd.read_file("%s" % gdb_file_path, layer=layer,rows=10000)
```

Comment: That looks like a bug. What versions of geopandas and Fiona do you have?

Comment: there is no bug actually, the issue was with my other code that gives an empty layer name.